# JavaFX runtime main method

Tags: java, javafx

The [Hello World-Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) of JavaFX says:

> The main() method is not required for JavaFX applications when the JAR file for the application is created with the JavaFX Packager tool, which embeds the JavaFX Launcher in the JAR file. However, it is useful to include the main() method so you can run JAR files that were created without the JavaFX Launcher, such as when using an IDE in which the JavaFX tools are not fully integrated. Also, Swing applications that embed JavaFX code require the main() method.

I tried this and its true, I can start my application without a `main` method.

However when I declare a `main` method an call `launch` from the `Application` class, the program still works.
The documentation of [Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) says, that the JavaFX runtime is creating an instance of the `Application` class and calls the `init` method.

But how does the JavaFX runtime start? I mean there has to be a `main` method somewhere, for everything to start. So Iam wondering if I declare a `main` method by myself, arent there two of them?

Comment: Extending Application is necessary for a JavaFX program. By doing this, you are using the main method in application by default when you run. If you created your own main method, it would override the application's main unless you called the super.main(args) before writing any additional code in it.

Comment: @faris `main` is `static`, it can't override anything or use `super.main`.

Comment: **Update:** The *JavaFX Packager* tool ([*javapackager*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719)) is now legacy. Supplanted by the *jpackage* tool defined in [*JEP 392: Packaging Tool*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392) as of Java 16.

Comment: Related: [*I Want to Understand How abstract class Application's launch() method work in JavaFX*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76798326/642706)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've actually always been interested in how Java launches JavaFX applications, so I decided to debug the process. Some things before the rest of the answer:

- I did the debugging with JDK-10 for a standalone desktop application. Some quick glances at the JDK-11 source code suggests the process has not changed between versions.
- When I use `Application` I'm referring to the `javafx.application.Application` class.
- When I use "`main` method" I'm referring to the `public static void main(String[] args)` method. Similarly, "main class" refers to the class containing the `main` method.
- All links for source code point to the OpenJDK Mercurial repository.
- Virtually all of this is an implementation detail and is subject to change without notice.

---

## Summary

When launching a JavaFX application, if the main class is a subclass of `Application` then the Java launcher uses **it's own, internal main class**. This internal class is responsible for initializing the JavaFX toolkit. Once the toolkit is initialized, one of two things can happen.

1. The `Application` subclass **has** a `main` method.

   - In this case, some internal JavaFX code invokes the `main` method. It is now the developers responsibility to finish launching the application via `Application.launch`.
2. The `Application` subclass **does not have** a `main` method.

   - In this case, the same internal JavaFX code launches the application itself. The first case eventually ends up in the same place this case does.

Basically, any `main` method declared in `Application` subclasses are not "normal" `main` methods. Think of this behavior like this:

- The internal `main` method acts as the entry point for the Java application—just like all "normal" `main` methods
- The `Application` subclass' `main` method serves as an optional entry point for the JavaFX application, where the JavaFX toolkit is already initialized.

---

## Detailed Answer

First, it is not the case that you "override" the `main` method of the `Application` class; the `Application` class has no `main` method. What actually happens is that Java uses it's own main class whenever the application's declared main class is a subclass of `Application`. For posterity, a main class can be declared using one of the following:

- Specifying it on the command line (file): `java -cp <classpath> foo.Main`
- Specifying it on the command line (module): `java -p <modulepath> -m foo/foo.Main`
- Specifying it in the JAR manifest: `Main-Class: foo.Main`
- (Another way I'm forgetting?)

### The Steps

These steps assume a JavaFX application. Most of this doesn't happen if launching a "regular" Java application.

#### Step 1: Load the Main Class

An internal class, `LauncherHelper`, checks and loads the main class via a method named `checkAndLoadMain`. This method is responsible for resolving the main class based on how the main class was declared (described above). Once found, this method checks whether or not the main class is a subclass of `Application`. If it is, then **the main class is changed** to a static inner class: `LauncherHelper$FXHelper`. Then some validation is performed and the `Class` is returned to, I assume, native code.

*Relevant code:*

- [`java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/launcher/LauncherHelper.java)
- [`java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/launcher/LauncherHelper.java#l541)
- [`java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/launcher/LauncherHelper.java#l840)

#### Step 2: Invoke the `main` Method

After the main class has been found, loaded, and validated it is called from (I assume) native code. Since we are talking about a JavaFX application the main class is now `LauncherHelper$FXHelper`. The `main` method of this class does one simple thing: Invoke internal JavaFX code via reflection.

*Relevant code:*

- [`java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/launcher/LauncherHelper.java#l934)

#### Step 3: JavaFX Pre-Startup

The code invoked by step 2 is inside a class named `LauncherImpl`; specifically, the `launchApplication(String,String,String[])` method. This method appears to do similar things as `LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain` except more specific to JavaFX.

I believe this method is similar to `checkAndLoadMain` because the `checkAndLoadMain` method validated the `FXHelper` class, which is obviously valid. However, `launchApplication` needs to validate the `Application` subclass.

*Relevant code:*

- [`javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java)
- [`javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java#l239)

#### Step 4: JavaFX Startup

The next method called is `launchApplicationWithArgs(ModuleAccess,String,String,String[])`. This method is responsible for starting the JavaFX toolkit. After this, it loads the `Application` subclass and, if present, `Preloader` subclass as actual `Class` instances. It does this on the *JavaFX Application Thread* but then returns to the main thread.

The code then takes one of two paths depending on the presence of a `main` method in the `Application` subclass:

1. **A `main` method exists:** Proceed to step 5.
2. **A `main` method does not exist:** Proceed to step 6 (launch the application directly)

*Relevant code:*

- [`javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java#l414)

#### Step 5: Invoke `main` Method of `Application` Subclass (Optional)

If there is a `main` method in the `Application` subclass it is invoked via reflection. It is now the responsibility of the developer to continue the launching procedure via a call to `Application.launch`. There are two overloads of the `launch` method:

1. `Application.launch(String...)`
2. `Application.launch(Class,String)`

The only difference being the first option uses the calling `Class` as the JavaFX `Application` subclass. Both end up calling `LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Class,String[])`. This latter method simply loads the `Class` of the `Preloader`, if needed, and then continues on to the next step.

*Relevant code:*

- [`javafx.graphics/javafx.application.Application.launch(String...)`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/application/Application.java#l267)
- [`javafx.graphics/javafx.application.Application.launch(Class,String...)`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/application/Application.java#l226)
- [`javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java#l139)

  - Note: Different method than the one linked in step 3.

#### Step 6: Finish Launching JavaFX Application

Now we're in the `LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Class,Class,String[])` method. This method does two simple things:

1. Create and start the *JavaFX-Launcher* thread which calls another method

   - `LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Class,Class,String[])`
2. Park the main thread (or whatever thread called `Application.launch`) in a `CountDownLatch` until the JavaFX toolkit exits.

The `launchApplication1` method will start the JavaFX toolkit if it hasn't already been started. Then it continues on to implement the standard JavaFX life-cycle. This involves creating the `Application` and, if present, `Preloader` classes then calling the `init()` and `start(Stage)` methods at the appropriate times on the appropriate threads. This life-cycle is the publicly defined behavior; virtually everything else mentioned here are implementation details.

*Relevant code:*

- [`javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java#l173)

  - Note: Again, different method from the ones linked in steps 3 and 5.
- [`javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java#l747)

### Non-`Application` Main Class

There is another way to launch JavaFX applications where the main class is not a subclass of `Application`, like so:

```
// main class
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(App.class, args);
    }

}

// JavaFX Application class
public class App extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // setup and show primaryStage
    }

}
```

Since `Main` is not a subclass of `Application` the change to `FXHelper`, in step 1, doesn't take place. This also means that steps 2-5 don't happen automatically. Instead, the call to `Application.launch` in `Main` starts this process at the final step: 6. That's why the the `launchApplication1` method also tries to start the JavaFX toolkit since it wouldn't have been started in this scenario.

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed question and your efford!

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer would probably be, that there is a `main` method declared in `Application`. And if another class, which extends from `Application`, has its own `main` method, the code would still be valid and the `main` method of `Application` will be ignored::

```
class Main extends OtherMain {
    public Main(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    /* If this method is removed, the main-method is called from OtherMain */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main("Called from Main-Class");
    }
}

class OtherMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main("Called from Other-Main-Class");
    }
}
```

Does this make sense?